# How is the following "form" called?

Tags: polynomials

What is the following "form" on the right side of the bi-implication called?

$$-k^3 + 10k^2 -31k + 30 \leftrightarrow -(k+5)(k+3)(k+2)$$

Comment: you can say: "factored form"

Comment: is it possible to "transform" every polynomial function with form "ax^3+bx^2+cx+d" into a factored form? Edit: From wiki: "The polynomial x2 + cx + d, where a + b = c and ab = d, can be factorized into (x + a)(x + b)." i think it also applies to higher polynoms :) Thansk Arnaldo

Comment: Look the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right side is the factorized form of the left.

The factorized form always exists if the field you're working in is [algebraically closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field). In particular, since the complex numbers are algebraically closed, every polynomial $p(x)$ can be factored into some constant times factors of the form $x-r_i$ where $r_i$ is a root of $p(x)$.

$$
p(x) = c(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_n)
$$

Where $p(x)$ is of degree $n$. Moreover, this factorization is unique up to the ordering of the linear factors $x-r_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Its simply factorised form.

Yes you can factorised in most cases and in some cases you get imaginary values.

Answer (score 0):

Every polynomial can be factored as

$$a_1x^n + a_2x^{n-1} + ... a_n x + a_{n+1} = a_1(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_{n-1})(x-r_n) $$

where $r_1,r_2,...,r_n$ are the roots of the polynomial (they may be complex).